# How do i change this code to scrape a table

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am struggling to data scrape this website:

`https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/widget?pageId=cu7nt&compId=comp-kesofw00&viewerCompId=comp-kesofw00&siteRevision=947&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&tz=Europe%2FLondon&width=980&height=890&instance=k983l1LiiUeOz5_3Pd_CLXbjfadc08q1fEu54xfh9aA.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&currency=GBP&currentCurrency=GBP&vsi=795183b4-8f30-4854-bd85-77678dbe4cf8&consent-policy=%7B%22func%22%3A0%2C%22anl%22%3A0%2C%22adv%22%3A0%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ess%22%3A1%7D&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22bsi%22%3Anull%2C%22BSI%22%3Anull%7D`

This URL has a table but for some reason I am not able to scrape this into an excel file. This is my current code in Python and this is what I have tried. Any help is much appreciated thank you legends!

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/widget?pageId=cu7nt&compId=comp-kesofw00&viewerCompId=comp-kesofw00&siteRevision=947&viewMode=site&deviceType=desktop&locale=en&tz=Europe%2FLondon&width=980&height=890&instance=dxGyx3zK9ULK0A8UtGOrLw-__FTD9EBEfzQojJ7Bz00.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&currency=GBP&currentCurrency=GBP&vsi=57130cda-8191-488e-8089-f472928266e3&consent-policy=%7B%22func%22%3A0%2C%22anl%22%3A0%2C%22adv%22%3A0%2C%22dt3%22%3A1%2C%22ess%22%3A1%7D&commonConfig=%7B%22brand%22%3A%22wix%22%2C%22bsi%22%3Anull%2C%22BSI%22%3Anull%7D"
table_id = "theTable"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('table', attrs={"id" : theTable})
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm awful at EXEL, but did you try copying the table and pasting in spreadsheet without your program.

Answer (score 0):

The page is loading the data using JavaScript. You can find the URL using the Network tab of Firefox. Even better news, the data is in the CSV format so you don't even need an HTML parser to parse it.

You can find the CSV [here](https://wix-visual-data.appspot.com/app/file?compId=comp-kesofw00&instance=k983l1LiiUeOz5_3Pd_CLXbjfadc08q1fEu54xfh9aA.eyJpbnN0YW5jZUlkIjoiYjQ0MWIxMGUtNTRmNy00YzdhLTgwY2QtNmU0ZjkwYzljMzA3IiwiYXBwRGVmSWQiOiIxMzQxMzlmMy1mMmEwLTJjMmMtNjkzYy1lZDIyMTY1Y2ZkODQiLCJtZXRhU2l0ZUlkIjoiM2M3ZmE5OWItY2I3Yy00MTg0LTk1OTEtNWY0MDhmYWYwZmRhIiwic2lnbkRhdGUiOiIyMDIxLTAxLTMwVDAxOjIzOjAyLjU1MVoiLCJ1aWQiOiIzYWMyNDI3YS04NGVhLTQ0ZGUtYjYxMS02MTNiZTVlOWJiZGQiLCJkZW1vTW9kZSI6ZmFsc2UsImFpZCI6IjczYWE3ZWNjLTQyODUtNDY2My1iNjMxLTMzMjE0MWJiZDhhMiIsImJpVG9rZW4iOiI4ODNlMTg5NS05ZjhiLTBkZmUtMTU1Yy0zMTBmMWY2NmNjZGQiLCJzaXRlT3duZXJJZCI6ImVhYWU1MDEzLTMxZjgtNDQzNC04MDFhLTE3NDQ2N2EwZjE5YSIsImV4cGlyYXRpb25EYXRlIjoiMjAyMS0wMS0zMFQwNToyMzowMi41NTFaIiwiaGFzVXNlclJvbGUiOmZhbHNlfQ).

Comment: great , but how do i implement this into python to data scrape into an excel file?

Comment: Since the data is a CSV file, you can just save it as `whatever.csv` and Excel will open it without any problems. If you need it to be an `xlsx` file, you can use a converter program or a library like https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/ or https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Comment: I would really recommend staying with a CSV file unless it absolutely has to be Excel though. A lot more apps can handle CSV files and Excel can open it natively.

Comment: right yes ok how do i save this as a csv ?

Comment: This file is already a CSV. Either load it with the requests library and write it to a CSV, or use a command line tool like `wget` or `curl`.

Comment: yeh i really dont get it